# Gnome enable left top app name thing?

Tags: gnome, pop-os

I am running Pop!_OS 21.04. I don't really know why I haven't got it, but it appeared once when I connected HDMI. Disappeared after reboot. I even removed Workspaces and Applications buttons, but no luck.

Little "Terminal" menu here is what I'm talking about.

[image: Screenshot]

And "Pop!_Shop" there

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps it is a popup shop?

Comment: @JeremyBoden nope. It is a menu. There is one in some screenshots, but not all.